# Is there a better and/or faster way to execute this regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to run this command every 500ms, but running it once is enough to lag. Is there a solution to increase performance while the function still does the same thing?

```
$('#current-update > div.update-content > ol:nth-child(4) > li > div.info > p').each(function() {
    var matchthis = $(this).text().match(/\*(.*?)\*/g);
    if (matchthis) {
        var replacethis = $(this).html().replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<strong>$1</strong>")
        $(this).replaceWith('<p data-bind="html: parsedBody" class="body">' + replacethis + "</p>")
    }
});
```

Comment: You could skip the `matchthis` test and just do the replacement, I suppose.

Comment: To format code blocks, highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the toolbar.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Why do you need to run this every half-second?  It's not the regex that's lagging, it the DOM redraw from the `replaceWith()`.

Comment: @Blazemonger I tried that, however the issue with that is if I dump the test, people will not be able to copy or select anything, as the information will be overwritten before they are able to.

Comment: @RocketHazmat To format text, and lets say someone adds a comment to that post, then that must be formatted. Also, isn't the `replaceWith()` only executed if something matches the parameters?

Comment: @user5294195: So why not just run it after the user posts the comment?  Why do it every 500ms?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I thought about that, but then when they go to change posts it would have to be executed again, and I'm not sure how to test for when the post is done loading, and then execute the command.

EDIT: Not to mention if someone ELSE posts a comment.

Comment: @user5294195: It wouldn't be executed *again*, you'd just need it to run the one time.  How are you loading the posts?  If it's an AJAX call, you can just run this in its callback.

Comment: Also it *may* be better to use jQuery's `.wrap()` instead of `replaceWith()`, but I'm not sure.  It may be lagging because you are running this function for every post, not just the one(s) that need it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Well, that's the problem in itself, if I owned the site I could do this much easier, but instead I develop a Chrome Extension for it, so manipulating things is not nearly as easy.
The posts are loaded by going to a different link, lets say your at example.com/updates/1234 and you click on another post, that post brings you to example.com/updates/4321 without re-loading the page (most of the time)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Checking what posts need it is what the `.match()` does, it doesn't run the second part to replace it unless something matches the `.match()` parameters. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not slow because of the regex. It's slow because somewhere in your code I suspect these paragraph tags are being dynamically updated every 500ms with comments inside them, and then you are iterating over them one by one to change the value.

The first rule about manipulating the dom - is don't manipulate the dom more than once in one sitting. This is often overlooked due to the new influx of angular,bootstrap, buildscript, data-binding, jquery developers that haven't learnt the importants of smooth web interaction.

Every time you read the dom with a jquery selector - $('#getThis') takes rendering time. Everytime you render something on the dom  - $('#getThis').html('add this') takes rendering time. Combine both actions in an iteration multiplies this, especially if you are doing it on a timer.

What you have ended up with now is slow not because of the regex, but because of the multiple dom manipulation, and re-reading the dom on every iteration.

Rethink your architecture. It's not going to get faster than this unless you read a whole html block, iterate over the string with regex, then write into the dom in one go.

good luck

Comment: After a while, I optimized my code a little, still could be done a lot differently, It checks for if an update is needed to any one paragraph block  (could be up as far as 500 at a time and thats not uncommon!) so I basically put a timer on a 1000ms (or 1s) and if it is needed, it will only change one at a time, little slow, at some point I should look into doing it with pure JavaScript.